# JList with JCheckBox

Tags: java

What I have tried to do is JList with checkbox. I am unable to select multiple item. When I do so, already selected item gets deselected. What I have missed here?

```
JList recipientsList = new JList(
            new RecipientWrapper[] { new RecipientWrapper("apple"), new RecipientWrapper("orange"),
                new RecipientWrapper("mango"), new RecipientWrapper("paw paw"), new RecipientWrapper("banana") });
        recipientsList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        recipientsList.setCellRenderer(new CheckboxListRenderer());

      class CheckboxListRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<RecipientWrapper>
      {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JCheckBox checkBox;
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,RecipientWrapper value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                                                      boolean cellHasFocus)
        {
          Component c = null;
          if(value != null)
          {
            getCheckBox().setText(value.toString());
            checkBox.setSelected(isSelected);
            value.setSelected(isSelected);
            c = checkBox;
          }
          else
          {
            c = new JLabel();
          }
          return c;
        }

        private JCheckBox getCheckBox()
        {
          if(checkBox == null)
          {
            checkBox = new JCheckBox();
          }
          return checkBox;
        }
      }
```

Comment: checkBox.setSelected(isSelected); is the wrong part.. It should be checkBox.setSelected(value.isSelected()); and need to repaint the JList with MouseListener..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the intended behavior of `JList`. You will need to hold down the **Ctrl** or **Shift** keys to select multiple values in the list.

If you want to change this behavior, you might want to consider using the `ActionListener` for the checkbox component and persisting that across events.